# belkinf5u409 to windows 7

Tags: windows-7

is a driver download available

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but **no**.

Belkin F5U409-CU USB PDA Ethernet Adapter

- Windows 7 32-bit: **Not compatible**
- Windows 7 64-bit: **Not compatible**

Source (Microsoft Windows 7 Compatibilty Center):

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/Windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Belkin%20F5U409-CU%20USB%20PDA%20Ethernet%20Adapter&v=Belkin&uid=&pf=0&pi=7&c=Networking&sc=Ethernet%20Adapters&os=64-bit

[ADDS]

But, also you can try **Windows Vista 32-bit** driver, it's seems some devices is working pretty with Vista drivers on **Windows 7**.

Here is the link address: http://www.belkin.com/support/article/?lid=en&pid=F5U409&aid=5368&scid=1